# Double CheckBox Creation mistake?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-2, c#-4.0

I have a foreach wich populates a table and one field of the line tables is:

```
<% foreach (var item in Model.List){%>
   <td align="center">
      <%: Html.CheckBox(item.ID.ToString(),item.isChecked)%>
  </td>
<%}%>
```

Inside my post function I was trying to get the Request.Form["45"]( 45 is a sample ID) and saw that the value "true,false" was being recieved.

Taking a look into the Code generated, I just saw that:

```
<input name="45" type="checkbox" value="true" /><input name="45" type="hidden" value="false" />
```

How its possible since Im just asking to generate one input? I dont know too if `Html.CheckBoxFor`is better to use in this case

Thanks !

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can read the explanation [here](http://forums.asp.net/t/1314753.aspx)

> the same approach that both Ruby on Rails and MonoRail use.
>
> When you submit a form with a checkbox, the value is only posted if
>   the checkbox is checked. So, if you leave the checkbox unchecked then
>   nothing will be sent to the server when in many situations you would
>   want false to be sent instead. As the hidden input has the same name
>   as the checkbox, then if the checkbox is unchecked you'll still get a
>   'false' sent to the server. When the checkbox is checked, the
>   ModelBinder will automatically take care of extracting the 'true' from
>   the 'true,false'

Why don't you use model so that model take care of it. Using request object is not recommended in asp.net-mvc  You may also use formcollection parameter in your actionresult and handle this scenario using [this](http://blog.ecofic.com/?p=346) approach.

You may always use html tags if helpers don't fit in your requirement.